# get child-class-name in constructor of father?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
class Grandfather1{
   constructor(childClassName){}
}

class Father1 extends Grandfather1{
  constructor(){
    super(childClassName (=== Child1) )
  }
}

class Child1 extends Father1{
  constructor(){
    super() // without passing `Child1` as parameter
  }
}
```

---

I have over 40 Child classes. I'm trying to save code and time.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: That's not proper OOP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Father1{
  constructor(){
    const childClassName = this.constructor.name
    console.log(childClassName)
  }
}

class Child1 extends Father1{
  constructor(){
    super() // without passing `Child1` as parameter
  }
}

new Child1();
```

**EDIT**

```js
class Grandfather1{
   constructor(){
       console.log(this.constructor.name)
   }
}

class Father1 extends Grandfather1{
  constructor(){
    super()
  }
}

class Child1 extends Father1{
  constructor(){
    super() // without passing `Child1` as parameter
  }
}

new Child1
```

Comment: thanks!! it looks like your answer doesn't work with my original problem. I updated my question. thanks so much again!!

Comment: Why you changed the original question? ... it has the same solution u just made it more complicated?!? ... look at the  EDIT